# Getting nilClass error while testing with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, controller

I'm testing my project with rspec and now I'm up to the controllers part. I'm testing this method:

```
def accept
  @app = App.find(params[:id])
  @invite = Invite.find_by(app: @app.name, receiver: current_dev.id)
  @dev = Developer.find(@invite.sender)
  @app.developers << @dev
  respond_to do |format|
    if @invite.destroy
      format.html { redirect_to @app, notice: 'A new developer joined your team!' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :destroyed, location: @app }
    else
      format.html { render :back }
      format.json { render json: @invite.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

and this is the test part:

```
it "should accept an invite (1)" do
  invite = Invite.create(:app => "test", :sender => "2", :receiver => "1")
  get :accept, :id => 1
  assert_response :success
end
```

but when I run the rspec command I get this error:

```
InvitesController should accept an invite (1)
Failure/Error: @dev = Developer.find(@invite.sender)

NoMethodError:
  undefined method `sender' for nil:NilClass
```

So I am assuming that the invite object is `nil` but I can't figure out why this happens. I test the function via browser and everything works fine. This is also causing same errors in different controller methods, every time just because my invite object is `nil`. Why is this happening?

Comment: Add a breakpoint in the `accept` method and see if `@app.name == 'test'`. If it is, then check if `current_dev.id == 1`.

Comment: My initial guess is that the `Invite` you created doesn't have an id of 1. If that is the case, then just add it as an argument to the `Invite.create` call in the spec.

Comment: wait, the 1 that you see as the :get parameter is due to my route for the method is: 
apps/:id/requests/accept

Comment: OK, still - what are the values of `@app.name` and `current _dev.id` in `accept`?

Comment: i get app.name == "test" but developer.id != 1

Comment: there you go, now enlighten us what is `current_dev` :)

Comment: due to login i have this: 
 before :each do
  developer = FactoryGirl.create(:developer)
  sign_in developer

 end
that i use to login a developer and use the function

Comment: or did you just asked to get the current_dev id?

Comment: Ok, so now what is `developer.id` in the test?

Comment: Ok, then in the `Invite.create` don't use `:receiver => "1"`, instead do `:receiver => developer.id`.

Comment: done, but test is still failing, same error

Comment: What is `current_dev.id` in `accept`?

Comment: do i need to check the value into the controller or in the test? because if i try to do it in the test (after get :accept) i get the error of course

Comment: Not after `accept` but in the middle of the method. Add a breakpoint/print/something.

Comment: It basically boils down to the value of `developer.id` in the test is not equal to the value of `current_dev.id`, we are trying to understand why, we need to know what both values are.

Comment: Ok, so to double check so far - `@app.name` is `'test'` and `current_dev.id` equals `developer.id` equals 5?

Comment: no wait: in my controller app name is something completely different from "test", it is a name like "Sheila Wilms" (OMG) while in the test i get the exact value "test"

Comment: Ok, so what is the id of the `App` that has the `name` of `"test"` (if it exists) and how did you create it (if you have)?

Comment: i did not create the app "test", i just assigned the :app value for invite to have name "test"

Comment: There you go. Create an `App` with name of `"test"` in `before :each` and pass it's id similarly to how you did it with `developer`.

Comment: do i need to something like: invite = Invite.create(:app => @app.name, etc.) ?

Comment: More like `let(:app) { App.create(:name => 'test') }` and then in the actual test - `get :accept, :id => app.id`.

Comment: it worked!!! thanks a lot! :) last thing, i get redirect code (302) but i guess is fine because i use
redirect_to @app
in the controller right?

Comment: Exactly, http 302 is used for redirects.

Comment: That's perfect. Thanks again!

Comment: Ok, now if you are perfectly satisfied with this resolution, create an answer to your question that explains what the issue was, how you debugged it and how you fixed it to cement your understanding and so that developers that come upon this question with a similar issue will find the post helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED:

- Main reason things weren't working: mismatch between created invite parameters and current parameters (`app`, `current_developer`)
- Debug: setting breakpoints/printing values of what was needed in the controller and what was needed in the model.
- Fixing: created objects that were missing in order to match parameters; correct solution was

```
it "should accept an invite (1)" do
  invite = Invite.create(:app => @app.name, :sender => "2", :receiver => @developer.id)
  get :accept, :id => @app.id
  assert_response :redirect
end
```

Comment: Nicely done, accept it in two days once the system allows you to.